# Invalid bound statement

Tags: java, spring, configuration, mybatis

I just followed mybatis's official documentation to write a demo. It works fine when I just use annotation. But when I try to mix to use annotation and xml mapper files, it goes wrong with exception "invalid bound statement". Well,I though may something I did wrong, so I get back to code just with xml mapper files without any annotation,but still goes wrong.
 I just read over official docs many times still can not find any useful information. could you someone help me to analyse what the hell is going on, thanks a lot,because it drives me so much crazy.

Here are the codes:

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan("mapper")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyBatisConfig
{
    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception
    {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sqlSessionFactory.setDataSource(MysqlDS());
        //sqlSessionFactory.setTypeAliasesPackage("entity");
        return sqlSessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource MysqlDS()
    {
        //PooledDataSource ds = new PooledDataSource();
        UnpooledDataSource ds = new UnpooledDataSource();
        ds.setDriver(DBConfig.driverClass());
        ds.setUrl(DBConfig.Url());
        ds.setUsername(DBConfig.username());
        ds.setPassword(DBConfig.password());
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager()
    {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(MysqlDS());
    }
```

mapper:

```
public interface MemberMapper
{
    @Select("SELECT * FROM r_test")
    @Results({
            @Result(column = "username", property = "username")
    })
    List<Tester> memberList();

    @Insert("INSERT into r_test (username, password) VALUES (#{username}, #{password})")
    void create(Tester tester);

    Tester getMember(Integer id);
}
```

entity

```
private int id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String time;
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="mapper.MemberMapper">

    <select id="getMember" resultType="Tester" parameterType="java.lang.Integer">
        select * from r_test where id=#{id}
    </select>

</mapper>
```

Comment: What is your exact error?

Comment: I just put the error info at the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `@Mapper` annotations in XXMapper.java, like this:

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {
    
    int deleteByPrimaryKey(Integer id);
    int insertSelective(User record);
    User selectByPrimaryKey(Integer id);
    int updateByPrimaryKeySelective(User record);
    int updateByPrimaryKeyWithBLOBs(User record);
    int updateByPrimaryKey(User record);
    
    @Select("select * from t_user where username=#{username}")
    User selectUserByUsername(String username);
    void insertUser(@Param("user") User user);
    User selectUserByUsernameAndPassword(HashMap<String, Object> hashMap);
    User selectUserById(int id);    
}
```